# Array Out of Bounds Exception with Hashmap Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to put together a hashmap with a char array as the value and a string as the key. I'm trying to print out the Keys and Values but keep getting an array out of bounds exception. I'm not sure what the problem is. (Also I might be trying to print out the map incorrectly; I'm kind of just going off other posts). Can someone help me out with the logic of this. Thanks for any help. Here is my code:

```
public class MapExample {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

       Map<String,char[]> mp=new HashMap<String, char[]>();

       char[] words = new char[2];
       words[0] = 'a';
       words[1] = 'b';
       words[2] = 'c';

       mp.put("1", words);
       mp.put("2", words);
       mp.put("3", words);

       Set s=mp.entrySet();
       Iterator it=s.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
        {           
            Map.Entry m =(Map.Entry)it.next();
            int key=(Integer)m.getKey();
            String value=(String)m.getValue();

            System.out.println("Key :"+key+"  Value :"+value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays are zero based. Increase the array size of `words` so that you can assign an element at index `2`

```
char[] words = new char[3];
```

Comment: Ok, but now I get java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer as an error, any ideas?

Comment: @dave: If you have another question, please post another question instead of discussing in the comments.

Comment: @dave your key is a `String` rather then an Integer, hence the `CCE`. Use Integer as a key instead

Comment: @Reimeus fixed those problems. thanks. Although it produced another type of error - which I guess I'll post in a different question

Answer (score 6):

```
   char[] words = new char[2];
   words[0] = 'a';
   words[1] = 'b';
   words[2] = 'c'; <-- HERE
```

You create a two elements array but put three items in it.

Arrays in Java have a *fixed* size which cannot be modified once they are initialized.

And then:

```
String value=(String)m.getValue();
```

This won't work: a `char[]` is not a `String`!

You have to:

```
String value = new String((char[]) m.getValue());
```

But you should you your map's `.entrySet()`, really.

Answer (score 3):

`new char[2]` does not mean "make a new array with indexes that go up to 2". It means "make a new array that can hold 2 values", and as array indexes start at 0, the indexes go from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

words[2] is the culprit here! The array words is or size 2. So you can only have 
Words[0] and words[1]

Answer (score 1):

The integer argument used when we create a new array is not the highest index that should be available in that array but rather the *actual size* of the array. Therefore, as others have said, you would want

```
char[] words = new char[3];
```

to create an array capable of holding three elements.